# Canonical way to convert an array of strings in C to a Python list using Cython

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, cython, dereference

I'm using Cython to interface a C library with Python. A library function returns an array of null-terminated strings with type `char**` and I want to convert this to a Python `list` of `str`. The following code works, but it seems fragile and clunky and I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it:

```
# myfile.pyx

from cython.operator import dereference

def results_from_c():
    cdef char** cstringsptr = my_c_function()

    strings = []

    string = dereference(cstringsptr)
    while string != NULL:
        strings.append(string.decode())
        cstringsptr += 1
        string = dereference(cstringsptr)

    return strings
```

In particular, is it ok to get the next string in the array with `cstringsptr += 1` like one would do in C with e.g. `cstringsptr++;`? Is this in general a robust way to convert arrays to lists? What if e.g. memory allocation fails or the string is not null terminated and it loops forever? It seems to me like there should be a simpler way to do this with Cython.

Comment: The callee must check the allocation and guarantee that the last pointer is NULL. It it does not then there is nothing you can do and the same applies in a C code (this is a bug and it has to be fixed in the callee function). Your input is not very common do I do not think there is a simpler way (there are faster ways though). A better C interface would be to write the number of returned strings in an output parameter (pointer to an int).

Comment: Thanks @JérômeRichard. Unfortunately the C interface only provides `char**` and no way to write the item count to some `int`. You allude to faster ways to perform my example code - can you suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the answer of @alexis, *in term of performance*, using `append` is quite slow (because it use a growing array internally) and it can be replaced by direct indexing. The idea is to perform two walk to know the number of strings. While a two walks seems expensive, this should not be the case since compiler should optimize this loop. If the code is compiled with the highest optimization level (`-O3`), the first loop should use very fast SIMD instructions. Once the length is known, the list can be allocated/filled in a much faster way. String decoding should take a significant part of the time. UTF-8 decoding is used by default. This is a bit expensive and using ASCII decoding instead should be a bit faster assuming the strings are known not to contain special characters.

Here is an example of untested code:

```py
from cython.operator import dereference

def results_from_c():
    cdef char** cstringsptr = my_c_function()
    cdef int length = 0
    cdef int i

    string = dereference(cstringsptr)
    while string != NULL:
        cstringsptr += 1
        length += 1
        string = dereference(cstringsptr)

    cstringsptr -= length

    # None is just a null pointer so that this just allocates a 0-filled array
    strings = [None] * length

    for i in range(length):
        string = dereference(cstringsptr + i)
        strings[i] = string.decode()

    return strings
```

This makes the code more complex though.

Comment: I think you missed a `length += 1` inside the first loop. Or, alternatively, change the loop code to (only) contain `length += 1` and `string = dereference(cstringsptr + length)` and remove the `cstringsptr -= length` below. Doing one of those changes, the code works nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, sorry, I missed the `length += 1` indeed (fixed). Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to bring in optimization (the question was about simple and robust, and if the array was huge the OP would have mentioned it), then use a list comprehension. It is faster, simpler, and does not require a preliminary pass.

Comment: @alexis I would agree if it was a pure Python code, but here this is a Cython code and thus the loop is fast since the `for i in range(length)` is fully compiled to a native code and the `strings[i]` is compiled to a semi-native code (there is still reference counting here). Thus, direct indexing should be faster with Cython (`[None] * length` is very fast with both). `append` are slower because of the growing array strategy. (besides this, I agree for the question of the OP though it asked for this in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a valid C data structure, the strings *will* be null-terminated. The question is, how is the array of string pointers terminated? Either the library (or `my_c_function()`) ensures that there is a NULL after the last string pointer, or it makes the array length available in some other way. Make sure you know which it is, and don't make your loop terminate on a null pointer unless you are guaranteed that there will be one.

Comment: I just checked the source code of the library, and the string array returned by `my_c_function` is null terminated. Does Cython in this case allow syntax like `for individual_array_item_pointer in cstringsptr: ...`? It seems there is enough information here for Cython to automate much of my manual pointer management here.